# Finding the coordinates of the apex of a pyramid with square base

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, 3d

A pyramid with square base $ABCD$ and apex $E$ has a known coordinates for $A,B,C,D$, they are $A= (0, 0, 0), B = (a, 0,0), C = (a,a,0), D = (0, a,0) $ where $a$ is known.  In addition, the distances from the apex to the four vertices of the bases are also given.  Now I want to determine the coordinates of the apex $(x, y, z)$.

**My Attempt:**

Let $s_1 = EA, s_2 = EB, s_3 = EC, s_4 =ED $, then from the distance formula,

$s_1^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$

$s_2^2 = (x - a)^2 + y^2 + z^2$

$s_3^2 = (x - a)^2 + (y - a)^2 + z^2$

$s_4^2 = x^2 + (y - a)^2 + z^2$

Taking the differences,

$ s_1^2 - s_2^2 = 2 a x - a^2 $

$ s_1^2 - s_3^2 = 2 a x + 2 a y - 2 a^2 $

$ s_1^2 - s_4^2 = 2 a y - a^2 $

For this system of equations to be consistent, we must have

$ s_1^2 - s_2^2 + s_1^2 - s_4^2 = s_1^2 - s_3^2 $

That is,

$ s_1^2 + s_3^2 = s_2^2 + s_4^2 $

Otherwise there is no solution.

Assuming this condition is satisfied, we can do away with the second equation.  The first and third equations give $x$ and $ y$ because $a$ is known.  Plugging $x$ and $y$ into the first original equation gives the value of $z$.

Any comments/alternative solutions are welcome and highly appreciated.

Comment: Ghasheem, you should write $ s_1^2 - s_2^2 + s_1^2 - s_4^2 = s_1^2 - s_3^2 $ instead of $ s_1^2 - s_2^2 + s_1 - s_4^2 = s_1^2 - s_3^2 $.

Comment: @Angelo Thanks, corrected.

Comment: Great analysis! As a headstart for the consistency condition, there are 3 unknowns ($x,y,z$) and 4 equations ($s_1^2 = ..., s_2^2 = .., s_3^2 = .., s_4^2 = ...$). So the 4 equations cannot be independent and 1 equation should be obtainable by algebraic manipulations of the remaining 3. Implying that there needs to be one consistency condition.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the three spheres $S(A,s_1), S(B,s_2), S(C,s_3)$.

The apex (with coordinates $(x_a,y_a,z_a)$) is one of their two common points of intersection. We will choose the one with positive $z$ coordinate.

The intersection of the spheres with horizontal plane $ABCD$ are circles.

First, determine the [radical center](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadicalCenter.html) (or "power center") $P$ of these circles (intersection of radical axes of these circles 2 by 2). This center has coordinates $(x_a,y_a,0)$.

Now, in order to find $z_a$, erect a vertical line from this point $C$ : the apex is the point on this line which is at distance $s_1$ from $A$ (and therefore at distance $s_2$ from $B$, etc.)

---

Edit: Explanations about radical center.

When we have 3 circles with resp. equations :

$$\begin{cases}
\underbrace{x^2+y^2-2a_1x-2b_1y+c_1}_{p_1(x,y)}&=&0\\
\underbrace{x^2+y^2-2a_2x-2b_2y+c_2}_{p_1(x,y)}&=&0\\
\underbrace{x^2+y^2-2a_3x-2b_3y+c_3}_{p_1(x,y)}&=&0
\end{cases}$$

The radical axis is the point such that

$$p_1(x,y)=p_2(x,y)=p_3(x,y)$$

which implies by taking differences, that :

$$\begin{cases}
2(a_1-a_2)x-2(b_1-b_2)y+(c_2-c_1)&=&0\\
2(a_1-a_3)x-2(b_1-b_3)y+(c_3-c_1)&=&0
\end{cases}$$

which is a linear system of two equations with two unknowns (representing two "radical axes'), easy to solve.

Comment: I just added an edit for the computation of the radical center.

Comment: So the circles and vertical line at C  are always concurrent  ?

Comment: @Narasimham It is the (common points) of the **spheres** and vertical line at $C$ which are always concurrent. The (diameter) circles are not concurrent in general.